# Why do commas take up two bytes?

Tags: t-sql, unicode, byte, nvarchar

`select datalength(N','), unicode(N',')` returns `2` in the first column and `44` in the second. This means that commas take up two bytes, but can be stored using just the number 44. `,` is in the first 128 characters of unicode (44 is less than 128), so it should only take up one byte, just as 0x2C (the encoding of 44) does. Why does T-SQL report that it takes up two bytes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it does take up 2 bytes. As an `nvarchar` the character `,` is stored as `0x2C00`, not `0x2C`, and `0x2C00` is a 2 byte value. `nvarchar` stores all characters as USC-2 or UTF-16 (depends on if you are using a supplementary characters collation) in a 2 byte pair that can be (some will require more, especially if you aren't in a supplementary characters collation).

If you want it to be stored using 1 byte, you could need to use a UTF-8 collation, and `varchar`, and then characters that need more bytes would use more bytes (rather than being lost).